# Windows Live Messenger 2011 logging in on another location

Tags: windows, windows-live-messenger

I have got the message "you have logged in on another location" few times, even when i hadnt logged in on another location! Is someone hacking my account, and how can i see where is the other guy logged in ? I couldnt find more than "log off (my PC name)" Should i be concerned about this ? OR is this some kind of bug ?

**Edit:** i got the message when i was *already logged in*, i dont/did use other microsoft products with the liveID, i was idling and suddenly out of nowhere the message came to the tray!

Answer (score 0):

When you open your inbox, you automatically log in there, so this might cause this problem.
I don't think anybody is hacking your account; if so, there's no way you can see who's logged in with your account.

Comment: inbox? i dont use any mail from microsoft, and this login message came when i was already logged in :/

Comment: @winuser The same thing happened to me when Windows live messenger 2011 came out. I think its a bug from the system.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your old session isn't loggin off correctly. I wouldn't worry about it, since logging off at one location logs off all locations.

Answer (score 0):

I came late to this question. Based on what you are saying, someone could somehow be logging in as you. I can't think of another reason if you have not left some detail out inadvertently. To answer your sub-question: You can't see where the other login is taking place.

So let's assume that that is actually happening, I can't believe that no one has not said this yet: CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD ASAP. Also change your security question and answer.